# SQL Azure - SSMS - A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm attempting to rebuild an index on a table with 9.1 million rows.  It currently is at 88% fragmentation

Alter Index [MYINDEX] on [MYTABLE] REBUILD

From SSMS I'm getting the following after several minutes...

Msg 10054, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

From the Management Portal I get the following after several minutes...

Run Transact-Sql command failed
Failed to read the status of the response.

Not sure what to try at this point.

Comment: Ended up dropping some other indexes on the table, then using the Rebuild, then adding the indexes back in.  That allowed me to rebuild the index successfully.  I don't really feel like I solved the problem, just worked around what was a large operation.

Comment: Are you saying the other indexes on the table affect the rebuild of the index you specify in the rebuild?  Didn't know this...

Answer (score 0):

You might try CREATE INDEX...WITH DROP_EXISTING instead.  Just script the existing index as CREATE and add the DROP_EXISTING option like the example below.  This will be more efficient since it leverages the existing index structure, thus avoiding the clustered index scan and sort.  This method will reduce fragmentation but will not address index corruption like REBUILD can.

```
CREATE INDEX [MYINDEX] ON MYTABLE
(
    [MYCOLUMN] ASC
)WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It's the Primary Key and I got a message back saying it couldn't create the index because the definition was different.  Sorry, I don't have the exact message in front of me.  Ended up dropping some other indexes on the table, then using the Rebuild, then adding the indexes back in.  That worked ok.

Comment: You need to add the UNIQUE keyword to rebuild the primary key index with the CREATE INDEX syntax, and specify (or omit) CLUSTERED depending on the existing primary key index type.